# react native : how to filter specific data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter

How do I filter the first list by getting the second list :

**this is the first list data :**

```
[
  {
    "stateID": 1,
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 2,
    "name": "Madame Green"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 3,
    "name": "Madame Yellow"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 4,
    "name": "Madame Red"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 5,
    "name": "Earthquake"
  }
]
```

**this is the second list data that i want get:**

```
[
  {
    "stateID": 1,
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 2,
    "name": "Madame"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 5,
    "name": "Earthquake"
  }
]
```

**this needs be the filter :**

```
{stateList.filter(option => <Picker.Item label={option.label} key={option.key} value={option.value} />)}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: can you please show me your example in my code ?

Comment: `const filteredList = fullList.filter( item => ( item.stateID === 1 || item.stateID === 2 || item.stateID === 5 ) );`

Comment: ok and than i did like this :
 {filteredList.map(option => <Picker.Item label={option.label} key={option.key} value={option.value} />)}

but its not works

Answer (score 1):

For filter i would do as follows

```js
let data_first = [
  {
    "stateID": 1,
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 2,
    "name": "Madame Green"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 3,
    "name": "Madame Yellow"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 4,
    "name": "Madame Red"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 5,
    "name": "Earthquake"
  }
];

let data_second = [
  {
    "stateID": 1,
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 2,
    "name": "Madame"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 5,
    "name": "Earthquake"
  }
]

let res = data_first.filter(v=>!(data_second.some(e=>e.stateID === v.stateID)))

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const d1 = [
  {
    "stateID": 1,
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 2,
    "name": "Madame Green"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 3,
    "name": "Madame Yellow"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 4,
    "name": "Madame Red"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 5,
    "name": "Earthquake"
  }
]

const d2 = [
  {
    "stateID": 1,
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 2,
    "name": "Madame"
  },
  {
    "stateID": 5,
    "name": "Earthquake"
  }
]


let arr1 = d1.filter(e => {
   return d2.some(item => item.stateID === e.stateID); // take the ! out and you're done
});
```

**Output:**

```
Output: [
  { stateID: 1, name: 'Emergency' },
  { stateID: 2, name: 'Madame Green' },
  { stateID: 5, name: 'Earthquake' }
]
```

Comment: Madame is not common on both array so you will get Emergency and Earthquake as a output if you do filter by name not by stateID